# React Redux Multiple Actions, want to trigger a single render

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

New to react/redux so bear with me :).

When selecting a regionlevel from a dropdown, I want to store the selected RegionLevelId, and make an API call to fetch the regions that belong to this RegionLevel.

At first I was storing this regionLevelId in the regionLevelReducer, which made it so that I only triggered one state change.

However, I'm saving more selected options in my state so I figured it might be cleaner to make a "selectOption" reducer that stores the selectedIds.

The point is now however, that when I select a regionLevel from the dropdown, I have to make two action calls. One to store the regionLevelId, and one to fetch data from the API. This renders the page twice, which is unnecessary.

I was wondering if it's possible to call two actions, while rendering AFTER these two actions have been completed. Now it renders in between these two actions.

I'm not sure if this is defying of how redux should be used. But I'm interested in how people would solve this problem.

The action I'm using atm:

```
export function selectRegionLevel(regionLevelId) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch({
      type: "SELECT_REGION_LEVEL",
      payload: regionLevelId
    });
    dispatch({
      type: "FETCH_REGIONS",
      payload: {
        request: {
          url: `regionLevels/${regionLevelId}/regions`
        }
      }
    });
  };
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your requirement, i think what you are looking for is **Batched Action**. Take a look at [react-batched-actions](https://github.com/tshelburne/redux-batched-actions) which aims to solve this problem and is recommended by redux team in such scenerios.